# Celery_worker fixture in pytest, connection already closed error

Tags: python, django, celery, pytest

I have such pytest structure

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestClass:
    def test_celery_mht_notification_create(self, celery_worker, user):
        # some test logic
```

When I use `celery_worker` fixture, I get such error `psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed`

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the solution](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4511#issuecomment-578839033) they gave you in the [issue created](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/1000) on `pytest-django`:

> On another note, a workaround for me was running as transaction tests with
> `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)`

Digging a little more in the comments thread of the first link, what IMHO is [a cleaner solution](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4511#issuecomment-741877597) is presented, along of an explication of why it happens:

> If you're using e.g. Py.test and want to use the in-process worker, you can do something like

```py
def pytest_configure():
    from celery.fixups.django import DjangoWorkerFixup
    DjangoWorkerFixup.install = lambda x: None
```

> to disable the worker fixups, which are unnecessary within this context.